# Why is my grid using GET if I set mType to POST?

Tags: post, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid. Here is my pared-down code for the grid:

```
$("#users").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',
    url: 'AjaxProxy.cfm',
    mType: 'POST',
    gridview: true,
    colModel: [
        {name: 'lastname', label: 'Last Name'},
        {name: 'firstname', label: 'First Name'},
        ... more columns ...
      ],
    height:'auto',
    autowidth:true,
    caption:'Users',
    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[10,20,50],
    sortorder:'asc',
    sortname: 'lastname',
    ignoreCase: true, // case-insensitive filtering
    pager: '#pager',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "ROWS", //our data
        page: "PAGE", //current page
        total: "TOTAL", //total pages
        records:"RECORDS", //total records
        cell: "", //not used
        id: "0" //will default first column as ID
    },
    postData: postData
});
```

I recently added in the `mType: 'POST'`. However, when I output the request_method in the AjaxProxy.cfm file it indicates that it's using a GET, and all the grid params are being passed in the URL rather than as POST values. Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools also indicate that it's using GET. Why is it still using GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exist **no** `mType` option, only `mtype`. All names are case-sensitive in JavaScript. The usage of

```js
mtype: 'POST'
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: @froadie: You are welcome! The problem: one can see errors of other more easy as his own one. So we are the people.